# Groovy: No such DSL method 'ansible' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have this complex groovy script for jenkins that looks something like

```
def run_pipeline() {
  try {
    stage('Build') {
      sh "docker build . -t ansible"
    }
    stage('Linux Common Tag') {
      def stage_common = [
        [tag: 'common', serial: '100%', user: "${env.ANSIBLE_USER}", playbook: 'platform.yml'],
      ]

      run_stages(stage_common, serial)
    }
}

def run_stages(stages, serial) {
  stages.each { phase ->
    def serial_percent=serial.containsKey(phase.tag) ? serial[phase.tag]: phase.serial
    ansible(phase.tag, phase.user, phase.password, limit=phase.limit, playbook=phase.playbook, serial=serial_percent)
  }

  execute_stages()
}

def ansible(tag, user, password, limit='', serial='100%' playbook='platform.yml') {
    // stuff in here
}
```

What we are getting is

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'ansible' found among steps
```

It seems to be happening in the `run_stages` function

Any input on what I am doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: Why the assignment of parameters when calling the function? And the order appears to different than defined in the function.

Comment: In `run_stages(stage_common, serial)`, where does `serial` come from? Your `try` is missing a `catch`/`finally` and closing braces and there is a missing comma between `serial='100%' playbook='platform.yml'`.

Comment: the missing comma was it.. if you want to add it as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that the command or "step" you are using is not valid. This is either because you typed something wrong, or a plugin is not installed that provides that step. I would guess you don't have the ansible plugin installed.

Comment: it should be calling `def ansible()` from below

Comment: Ah. I didn't look closely enough at the whole script.